# Excel date formula to convert text to YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

Tags: excel, date

I have one column in Microsoft Excel in which each cell has value in this format "17.03.2017". It's general text.

I want convert this string using excel date formula in the below format

2017-03-17 00:00:00 (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS)

Can you please share any suggestion. I am completely new to Excel.

Comment: At SO we typically help those that help themselves. Please show any efforts you have made to attempt to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: You want to specify a custom format code of `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`

Comment: ok. I am feeling generous: `=TEXT(DATE(RIGHT(K9,4),MID(K9,4,2),LEFT(K9,2)),"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS")` where K9 holds the general text version of the date

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Thanks a lot buddy.. it works.. (y)

Answer (score 0):

You can use format() on the date cell and then concatenate the time with it.

Good reads:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Format-numbers-as-dates-or-times-418bd3fe-0577-47c8-8caa-b4d30c528309

https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/format_date.php

Comment: link only answers are better suited as comments to the OP. These answer become useless if links die.